# Google SMTP not sending email from react native app via a REST API

Tags: laravel, react-native, rest, smtp, gmail

my Laravel project successfully sends emails using Google SMTP when triggered from my website but encounters issues when called from my React Native app via a REST API. But the api is calling from postman, successfully sending the mail

```
$message = "Testing mail";
$reciever_mail = $req->email;

\Mail::raw('Hi, '.$req->name.' welcome!', function ($message) use($reciever_mail){
   $message->to($reciever_mail)
   ->subject('Testing mail');
});
```

i tried with alternative smpt services like mailtrap, but im getting the same issues

Comment: was there any error message? Logs? stack trace?